# Shell script to find and replace value from csv file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am trying to write a shell script to search a cell value in a csv file and replace a corresponding cell in the same row.

Below is my csv file (`report.csv`)

> **#,Device,Status**
> 1,Device1,Used
> 2,Device2,Free
> 3,Device3,Free

This is want I wanted to do:

User will enter device name as input while executing the script.

e.g., Enter the device name:
user enters "Device2"

Next step: script should search for **Device2** in `report.csv`. If it finds **Device2**, check the value in the **status** column corresponding to it and, if the value is **Free**, replace it as **Used**, else exit the script saying **Device2 already in use**.

I have tried with following code

```
#!/bin/bash
dvc=""
FILE_HOME="/tmp/test/"

update_value () {  
  awk -F, -v d="$dvc" '$2==d{if($3=="Free")$3="Used"; else print d "In use"; input_value;}1' \
      OFS=, "$FILE_HOME"/report.csv > "$FILE_HOME"/report1.csv  
  mv "$FILE_HOME"/report1.csv "$FILE_HOME"/report.csv
}

input_value () {
  echo -e "Enter the device name:\n"
  read dvc
  update_value
}

input_value
```

This code is fine when the **if** statement is **true**.
But when the **if** statement is **false**, it is not calling function `input_value` from the else section.  It just prints **Device# In use** along with other entries in csv file to new file.

I get below output files

- when input is **Device2**:

  > **#,Device,Status**
  > 1,Device1,Used
  > 2,Device2,Used
  > 3,Device3,Free
- when input is **Device1**:

  > **#,Device,Status**
  > Device1 In use
  > 1,Device1,Used
  > 2,Device2,Free
  > 3,Device3,Free

Is this the right approach I am doing?
I would be happy to see if there a different/better approach to achieve the requirement.

Comment: the other post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381900/match-one-cell-and-replace-value-of-another-cell-in-csv-using-shell-script

Comment: you can edit the other post to clarify it

Comment: Be aware that your approach is not safe in a multitasking environment. With two users executing the script in parallel, strange things may happen. In a productive system, you may want some mutex mechanism like `setlock`

Comment: (1) You're having the problem that you're having because `awk` can't call shell functions. (2) Why are you trying to call `input_value` from the awk code? Your statement of your requirements / objectives says “if the value is `Free`, replace it as `Used`, *else **exit the script*** ” (emphasis added), yet it looks like you have written the code to *stay in the script and **ask the user for another device name***. Please decide what you want and express it clearly.

Comment: VTC’ing as POB just because the question asks “Is this the right approach I am doing?” and asks about “a better approach” seems like an awfully petty thing to do to a new user with a real question. (Is there something else about this question that makes it opinion-based? I don’t see anything.)

Comment: If the user *has to* type a device name that appears in your data, it might be more convenient – both for the programmer and the user – to use the shell `select` construct rather than asking for some random input: `select <destination_variable_name> in <choice_1> … <choice_k>`. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bash+select+example&t=canonical&ia=web

Answer (score 1):

Write your error message to `stderr`.

```
awk -F, OFS=, -v d="$dvc" '
    $2==d {
      if($3=="Free") $3="Used"
      else print d "In use" > "/dev/stderr"
      print
    }' $FILE_HOME/report.csv > $FILE_HOME/report1.csv
```

This will make it appear on screen (if `stderr` is not redirected), rather than in the standard output.

That being said, there are things you could do to make your script a bit simpler to work with. How about this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  FS=","
  OFS=","
  FILE_NAME="/tmp/test/report1.csv"
  print "Enter the device name:"
  getline d < "-"
}

$2==d && $3=="Free" {
  $3="Used"
  print > FILE_NAME
  next
}

$2==d {
  print d " in use" > "/dev/stderr"
}

{
  print > FILE_NAME
}
```

Invoke it with

```
$ script_name /tmp/test/report.csv
```

and/or wrap it in `bash` as you please.

Comment: (1) You set `FILE_NAME` and never use it, and you use `file1` and never set it.  I guess you got your wires crossed?  (2) Your script never writes to the standard output.  Why do you hardcode an output filename in the `awk` code, when you could much more flexibly have a shell script redirect the standard output from `awk`?

Comment: @Scott (1) I did, thanks. (2) - well this was an `awk` script intended as a replacement of the `bash` script in the question - where the file name is hard coded. The script _does_ write to `stdout`, in the `BEGIN` clause.

Comment: Oops; I overlooked that.

Comment: @Bex: looks like your script done the work for me :). Thanks for the help. Let me do some more analysis  with that and come back if get struck.. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you limited to shell and awk only?
Do you able to use SQLite to store your data or at least to parse it?

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import report.csv report
sqlite> update report set status="Used" where Device="Device2";
sqlite> select * from report;
 1,Device1,Used
 2,Device2,Used
 3,Device3,Free
```

Or may be you can use more general programming languages like Python for your task?

```
import csv

with open('report.csv') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
  for row in reader:
    if row['Device'] == "Device3":
      row['Status'] = "Used"
    print row

{'Device': 'Device1', 'Status': 'Used', '#': '1'}
{'Device': 'Device2', 'Status': 'Free', '#': '2'}
{'Device': 'Device3', 'Status': 'Used', '#': '3'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Since I do not have knowledge on SQLite and Python, I prefer to do with shell and awk as I am more comfortable with those.